# definition of projection operation for boolean functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

A boolean function $f$ over a set $A$ is a subset $X\subseteq A$ and $F$ is a set of boolean functions.

I am trying to check whether $F$ is closed under *projection*. And I really do not know what projection here means. It is easy to check whether $F$ is closed under intersection, I get any two functions $f_i,f_j\in F$ and check whether $f_i\cap f_ j$ (i.e., the intersection of the two subsets) belongs to $F$ or not.

For projection, how should it be defined and what closed under projection means?

Comment: $f$ is  not boolean function since $a$ is not boolean variable

Comment: You mentioned that $f(a)=0$ (under some conditions), so as far as I understand from this that $f$ is a function and $a$ is a variable to that function. But again you mentioned that $a \in f$. I could not make any sense from it. Could you please explain which point I am missing here?

Comment: @Rajada A subset can be "identified" with its indicator function $\mathbf 1_f(a)=\begin{cases}1&a\in f\\0&a\notin f\end{cases}$. The sets $f_i$ are treated as sets in most of the post above, except for the $f(a)=0$ equation, which should more precisely be written $\mathbf 1_f(a)=1$ (usually the indicator function is $1$, not $0$, in the set).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro true. I have subsets of the power set of A . Usually denotes by 1 if $a\in f$. will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

*This answer makes sense when $F$ is a subset of ${\cal P}({\cal P}(A))$, so that the elements of $F$ are "boolean functions", subsets of ${\cal P}(A)$, or alternatively functions $\{0,1\}^A\to\{0,1\}$. You stated that $F$ is a set of subsets of $A$, however, which is incompatible with this assumption. My only guess in this case is that the projections are the sets $f_a=\{a\}$ for $a\in A$, but this terminology is not as well-motivated.*

The projections are the sets $f_a=\{x\subseteq A\mid a\in x\}$, and "$F$ is closed under projection" means $f_a\in F$ for all $a\in A$.

To understand where the terminology comes from, consider an arbitrary boolean lattice, on three generators $x,y,z$ for concreteness. Here the elements include things like $x\land y$, $(x\lor z)\land \lnot y$, etc. These can also be thought of as functions $\{0,1\}^3\to\{0,1\}$, where we assign a value from $\{0,1\}$ to each of $x,y,z$ and evaluate the ANDs and ORs in the expression. In this context, the projection $p_1$ that selects the first coordinate from $v\in\{0,1\}^3$ is a boolean function, whose expression is just $x$. Similarly, the other projection functions are $y$ and $z$.

Now consider what this means if we instead have the boolean lattice being ${\cal P}(A)$ with union and complement as the operations. The function $p_i$ can be written explicitly as $p_i(v)=v_i$, and if we replace $v_i$ with $i\in v$ (where $v$ is now a subset of $A$) we get $v\in p_i\leftrightarrow i\in v$, which can be expressed as a class abstraction as $f_a=\{x\subseteq A\mid a\in x\}$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I'm not familiar with the right terms. I have a set of boolean functions where every function represents a subset of A. For example one function $f_1=\{a\}$ another $f_2=\{a,b\}$ another $f_3=\{\emptyset\}$ for $A=\{a,b\}$.

Comment: @seteropere In your example, $f_3$ is not a subset of $A$. Is there anything else you can tell me about your application or a particular problem you are trying to solve? The terminology still seems contradictory; as Leox points out a subset of $A$, or equivalently a function $A\to\{0,1\}$ is not usually called a "boolean function"; this is reserved for the case where the domain of the function is a boolean algebra like $\{0,1\}^A$, which would mean that $f$ should be a set of subsets of $A$.